# Customize table pagination for Html to pdf conversion

Tags: html, css, flying-saucer, openhtmltopdf

I'm currently using openhtmltopdf to convert an html to pdf. The html has a table1(no header) with 3 rows, then some text and then table2(with a header) which can have many rows. Assuming table2 is getting paginated across multiple pages, the pdf should look like this -

```
table1(on every page having atleast 1 row from table2)
some text(only on the page having 1st row of table 2)
table2 paginating with header repeating on every page
```

For repeating the header of table2 on all the pages, I am using -fs-table-paginate:paginate which works. But how do I repeat table 1 and the text as per the requirement? Really appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can either put the table 1 in the header of the page (it will appear on every page, not only on page containing table 2).

An other option is to include table 1 in the thead of table 2, with some CSS to make it appear as a separate table.
For example:

```
<head>
    <style>
       td{border:1px solid red}
       #table1, #table1 td{border: 0}
       table{-fs-table-paginate:paginate;border-collapse: collapse}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table2">
        <thead>
        <!-- Table 1 -->
        <tr>
            <td id="table1">
                <table>
                <tr><td>Table1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Value</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Header of table 2 -->
        <tr><td>Col name</td></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           (...)
        </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
```